# HTTPS in Nodejs - error:06065064 digital envelope routines evp_decryptfinal_ex bad decrypt

Tags: node.js, https, openssl, cryptojs, hapi.js

We tried to install our Hapis (Nodejs Version 14) Web service on our customer's server. It ran under HTTP for months, but when we went to enable HTTPS with the appropriate paths to the cert and key it fails when the service starts up with:

**error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_Decryptfinal_ex:bad decrypt**

Their certificate and key are generated using the Venafi online portal. It gave them a crt and key. The crt uses a Signature algorithm: sha256RSA, Signature hash algorithm of sha256, and Thumbprint algorith: sha1.

Also, the private key is a RSA PRIVATE KEY with Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED and DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC.

I am not sure what is going on, because HTTPS works fine on our development servers.

1. Is the problem in HapiJS?
2. Is the problem with the certificate or key themselves?
3. Is there an Node [option](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback) I need to be passing in when creating the service?

Please help.

Comment: That error is usually if not always due to providing the wrong passphrase to decrypt the (private)key. Check that, and avoid non-ASCII characters. You aren't clear if these are the same files (and you could test locally), although I hope not because you shouldn't be able to prove ownership of their domainname or vice versa. (For that matter, using some unknown online source is bad security practice, but that's out of scope of your Q and off-topic for SO anyway.)

Comment: Thank you sir. I updated the question with details of the crt and key. I am not specifying a passphrase as I didnt think I needed to, because I never had to in our test environment.

Comment: Yes, that key file is encrypted with a passphrase aka password so you need to supply the passphrase, using [passphrase option for tls.createSecureContext](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) (which is what https uses underneath). Alternatively, if acceptable to the users and any applicable policies or regulations, use commandline openssl to convert the encrypted keyfile to a nonencrypted one, then you don't need any passphrase.

Comment: If you move your comment to the answer panel, I will mark it as such

Comment: Just emphasising @dave_thompson_085 answer. :
"That error is usually if not always due to providing the wrong passphrase to decrypt"

This is just what I was looking for,  searching the web for that error message and found that it really means "wrong passphrase".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specified error `06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_Decryptfinal_ex:bad decrypt` occurs in an SSL/TLS connection using OpenSSL (which is what nodejs modules like tls and https actually use) when the privatekey is encrypted (with a passphrase) and the correct passphrase is not provided to decrypt it. The described file format, beginning with a line `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` followed by lines `Proc-Type:` and `DEK-Info:` is indeed one of the encrypted formats used by OpenSSL. Specifically this is the encrypted 'traditional' or 'legacy' format; the PKSC8 format added about 2000 but still considered new(!) uses `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` and no 822-style headers, only base64 (of the encrypted structure defined by PKCS8); see ursinely-verbose https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys/#52564 about OpenSSH's use of OpenSSL, which is basically the same as nodejs's use.

The `tls` module and others that build on it including `https` ultimately read the key(s) and cert(s) using [`tls.createSecureContext`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) which accepts in `options` a member `passphrase`, or if you need to use *multiple* keys (and certs) you can provide a passphrase for each key as described in the linked doc.

Alternatively you can avoid the need for a passphrase by converting the key to an unencrypted file, if acceptable under applicable security policies and regulations. (Good policies may prohibit this, but they usually also prohibit getting the privatekey from or providing it to any other system, especially one 'online' somewhere, and your customer is doing the latter.) To retain traditional format do

```
openssl rsa -in oldfile -out newfile 
# and give the passphrase when prompted, or see the man page about -passin
```

or you can use the 'new' PKCS8 format with

```
openssl pkey -in oldfile -out newfile
# technically only in release 1.0.0 up, but pretty much everyone is there now
#
# or in all versions back to about 2000
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in oldfile -out newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this error occured after pulling some old code that was workign to a fresh system, I was using too current of a node Version, I downgraded from 17 to 16 and that solved my problem.

Comment: I faced the error while building my project using yarn. After downgrading Node from 17 to 16 everything started to work. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Stalinko glad to here this helped, been running into this same error a lot recnetly with node 17. I like to install node via NVM https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, and then its very easy to switch versions wtih a command like NVM Use 16.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I would say that the accepted answer is good expect it does not provide an example where the passphrase is used.

Here's code that worked in my case for `express.js`

```
const server = https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync("./root/ca/cakey.pem"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("./root/ca/cacert.pem"),
      passphrase: "abcdefg",
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Secure server listening on port:${PORT}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried checking the github issues related to the TLS, handshake and versions. But couldn't find any.
The final fix was the one suggested by @Greggory Wiley.

Installed nvm - downgraded the node and npm versions. Recomplied the code. And it worked.

Comment: Best to upvote and comment on the original solution posted that worked for you instead of posting another solution as a fix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was exporting a certificate from windows to linux inside a docker using openSSL and facing this error.

The problem was in the **versions** of OpenSLL, when I was converting .pfx file to .crt and .key I was using **3.0.x** version on windows, and on linux I had **1.1.1** installed. After I did the same using the same version of OpenSLL on windows it worked.